# Authorizing a single aspx page with log in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have an `ASP.net` application where I have a page named **foo.aspx** where some secured data is placed.

I want to denny the access to this page to users not logged in, and this login **Username** and **Password** must set by me in `web.config` or somewhere else.

But I have a problem that there is already a **Admin Panel** which is restricted to normal users
by **Username** , **Password** I have set in `web.config` using authentication mode set to forms.

Now how can I restrict **foo.aspx** page as authentication code can't duplicate and also want separate log in page.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want two different login systems, with different login/pwd pair ? One who protects admin panel and one who protects foo.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, you could define  elements (after system.web closure) where you set a specific configuration for a specific zone/page of your app.

Eg:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
....
</system.web>
<location path="Foo.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

There, you may set a different authorization mode than the one in use by your app.

With the above example, your page won't be protected by the standard authorization mode configured globally, but you have the choiche to protect your page in a custom way, directly in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your foo.aspx page you have

```
    if(login == false)
      send them to login page;
```

This will make sure that they are logged in before they can even access the foo page.

Comment: Not to clear based on the question you asked, but if you want a page just for admins then use permision levels.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to have two different asp.net applications. You can still configure your IIS to have your Foo application in another folder / subdomain.

You can, however, try to develop your own AuthenticationModule which will need to have a list of urls protected by Admin-authent and a list of urls protected by Foo-authent, each one with its specific Login page and a default login-pwd pair or a table of users. Here's a tutorial for developing custom Authent module : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5353/Custom-Authentication-provider-by-implementing-IHt

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can add your page `foo.aspx` to a folder and you can protect this folder by adding a new `web.config` file

for example ,

```
Folder  
  -foo.aspx  
  -web.config
```

in new `web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><configuration>  
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```